# What is Starbucks populating the URL with when I login?

Tags: javascript, get, client-server

When I login to Starbucks my URL populates like this

```
http://sbux-portal.appspot.com/splash?mac=0c:84:dc:21:96:bd&apname=18:64:72:ce:58:d8
```

which is a GET request with parameters like this:

```
mac=0c:84:dc:21:96:bd
apname=18:64:72:ce:58:d8
```

and then immediately redirects to

```
https://digital.starbucks.com/?vh=439eafa068feaf8cfe59a4eaa7a31eed&MacAddr=0c:84:dc:21:96:bd&venue=07386&ts=1434977299
```

which I can see is a GET request with the parameters:

```
vh = 439eafa068feaf8cfe59a4eaa7a31eed
MacAddr = 0c:84:dc:21:96:bd
venue = 07386
ts = 1434977299
```

Is there a way to figure out what these parameters are?  Is there some where I can look?  Using `getmac` I can see my mac address is being sent and that `ts` appears to be a time stamp, but what are the other parameters for? ( Update: venue appears to be the store number )

As a side, how are they able to obtain my MAC address?  Are using JavaScript to do this ?

Comment: I'd assume venue is the Starbucks store number you're at. You can also do this in C#

Comment: @cadegalt GET probably in that case is GETing the data from the server. The Mac Address can be retrieved with PHP. The starbucks you're at will probably grab your mac address / venue, and then send i back to you. Then the client will send another request *this one* to the Starbucks website / not the local starbucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seemed to have guessed many of the parameters correctly yourself.  It looks like `apname` is also a mac address but likely of the local Starbucks router.

Also, because you can see your MAC address in the GET request and the client does not have access to this, it is being determined on the server, and being sent back to you.

This is why you see it in the redirect.